# How can I get a input's value and redirect to the specified HREF in one click?

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I'd done tried using my JavaScript to get information from the input to the localStorage.
However, when I add a link which need to perform at the same time, the information cannot store into localStorage.

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="list">
  <a class="item">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td width="100">Name</td>
        <td>:{{object.name}}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Description</td>
        <td>:{{object.description}}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>No of Pages</td>
        <td>:{{object.pages}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </a>
</div>
```

This is my JS:

```
$scope.bookep = function(object) {
  $localStorage.bookinfo=object;
  $localStorage.bookno=$scope.book.indexOf(object);
  location.href="editbook.html";
};
```

Even if I use `location.href="editbook.html";` in JavaScript or use a `href="editbook.html";` in html code both only redirect to the link, but the value does not get stored.

Comment: Sorry!What is your actual issue? Redirection not happening?

Comment: It has a function to run. If redirection and function call separately it works fine, but when I combine both in one click, only redirection happens.